# Role of spring container in spring mvc web application

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

We are developing a web application which uses spring mvc, rest, jquery, ajax and json. Also we use mongodb as our db. We use maven as build tool.
I have a project structure like below:

> - `eem` (parent pom)
>
>   - `eem-db` (sub module, and it is a Eclipse project for mongo db dao level and model resides here)
>   - `eem-net` (sub module, and it is again a Eclipse project for some networking code)
>   - `eem-webapp` (sub module, and it is a Eclipse web app project for web application, which has Spring MVC)

My doubt is about the design of our web application in which I'm not knowing how to use spring container on this web app.

Below are my requirements and need help:

1. Is it a correct way to have mongodb related dao in a separate project?
   (we use dependency on `eem-webapp` to get db code (as `.jar`) on our web app).
2. How can i use `@Autowired` on the model in my controller to get mongo db model "emp" (say, `com.eem.db.model.emp`)? i.e What configuration do i need to provide on my `eem-webapp` to autowire `emp` (and all model classes) model to my controller?
3. I want to instantiate a class (say, `com.eem.net.discovery.discover`)  from `eem-net` on my controller. How should i do this from spring config file. I know using new is not necessary when we are on spring container. What kinda DI i should use for this situation?

Any pointers for my learning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practique is create one session factory bean (scope=singleton) that you can @Autowired in all your Controllers, you can also create one pool connections to managing your clients db requests.

For this you can create your own .jar, and use your own .jar classes to register your bean in your spring container.

Comment: mongodb pool connection in my webapp spring config file?  can you please elaborate based on my questions?